# Categorical semantics of Agda

Tags: type-theory, agda, inductive-type, coinductive-type, denotational-semantics

I would like to know the state of the art regarding the categorical semantics of the type theory implemented by Agda — or at least some approximation of that type theory that is amenable to mathematical analysis.

I mostly understand the semantics of the individual components that go into this type theory, such as inductive types, recursive functions defined by pattern matching, coinductive records, corecursive functions defined by copattern matching, etc.  (For purposes of this question, let's ignore more recent features like rewriting, cubical type theory, two-level type theory, etc.  I would prefer to work without K, but for the most part I don't even understand the situation with K.)  But Agda also allows essentially any collection of these features to be combined in a mutual family of definitions, and for the most part I don't understand how such combinations work semantically.  Here's what I do know:

- Inductive types are initial algebras for polynomial endofunctors, and coinductive types are terminal coalgebras for such.
- Mutual families of non-interdependent inductive types are fairly well-understood, and can be reduced to single indexed inductive families.
- Definitions by pattern-matching and copattern-matching can be reduced to the universal properties of inductive and coinductive types, as in [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2628136.2628139).
- Mutual families of inductive types that depend on each other are called inductive-inductive types.  The only reference I know of for the semantics of these is [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-22944-2_6), which I believe considers only two-element inductive-inductive families ($A:\mathsf{Type}$ and $B:A\to \mathsf{Type}$), characterizing their semantics in terms of initial dialgebras but not discussing which categories admit such things.  Possibly inductive-inductive definitions can also sometimes be partially reduced to ordinary indexed inductive families.
- Mutual families of inductive types together with recursive functions defined on them are called induction-recursion.  All the papers I know of about induction-recursion consider only the case of an inductive type family defined mutually with a family of recursive functions on it, where the functions take one input from one of the inductive types and their codomains are fixed.  Agda, by contrast, allows the recursive functions in an inductive-recursive group to include arbitrarily many of the inductive types in their domain *and* their codomain.  Semantically, [this paper](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/%7Epeterd/papers/InductionRecursionInitialAlgebras.pdf) for instance describes the aforementioned restricted kind of induction-recursion in terms of initial algebras on a slice category, but doesn't say anything about the more general sort of induction-recursion in Agda, or discuss which categories admit such things.
- Mixing induction and coinduction is weird, already when it's [nested](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/961/98) and certainly also when it's mutual.  I have no idea what this even could mean semantically, and I'm not familiar with any work on it.  How can you define something having a mapping-in universal property simultaneously with something having a mapping-out universal property?

So what I am most curious about is:

1. What is the categorical semantics of inductive-recursive (or inductive-inductive-recursive) definitions where the inductive types can appear in both the domains and codomains of the recursive functions?
2. In what categories (locally presentable, Grothendieck toposes, etc.) can such inductive-recursive definitions be *constructed* (not merely characterized when they happen to exist)?
3. What is the categorical semantics of mutual inductive-coinductive definitions, and in what categories can it be constructed?

It's possible this would be a better question for MathOverflow or CSTheory stackexchange, but I thought I'd try here first.

Comment: This is such a good question, and I have always been very frustrated that this area of the literature has mainly focused on foundational aspects (e.g. proposing or taking IR as an axiom of set theory, relating it to other potential axioms of set theory) rather than mathematical aspects (finding examples of models in general categories).

Comment: The closest thing I ever found to an answer to the question about IR is in the paper "Fibred Data Types" (https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/fredrik.nordvall-forsberg/papers/fibred_lics2013.pdf) of Ghani, Malatesta, Forsberg, and Setzer, in the section "Existence of initial algebras". I am curious what your take on this paper is.

Comment: @JonathanSterling Thanks for that link!  In fact I read that paper when it came out, but when writing this question I wasn't able to find it again.  I am very happy that that paper is trying to understand the categorical analogue of IR, but I'm unsatisfied by two aspects.  One is that I find it rather sketchy.  E.g. one of the central assumptions, that $\mathcal{E}^{sp}$ has coproducts, fails in some of the examples, but this is only addressed by a brief claim in Remark 2 that you can use a different functor instead.  And no proofs are given in the "Existence of initial algebras" section.

Comment: The second aspect I'm unsatisfied with is that, although they don't attempt to specify any general syntax corresponding to their semantics (which I can't really fault them for, since Peter and I did the same thing in our HITs paper), it seems to me that the fibrational perspective is mainly applicable to inductive definitions of types or families of types (the base category $\mathcal{B}$) together with recursively defined families of *types* dependent on one or more of them (the total category $\mathcal{E}$).

Comment: I don't see any indication that this reaches the generality of Agda, where the codomains of the recursive functions in an IR definition can be arbitrary types rather than the universe, including even one of the types currently being defined by induction.

Comment: In looking for my previous conversations about that paper, I also just discovered https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/51021/28847, which I need to go read now...

Comment: Also, after asking this question I learned about [this open issue](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/1556) which points out that Agda currently permits mutual definitions that go even beyond induction-recursion in the direction of "very dependent types".

Comment: Ha, I think that other cstheory thread was such a train wreck... I never saw so many (apparently) incorrect or incomplete arguments in one place. 

Anyway, I agree with you that I have never seen anything that really explains the generality of what Agda supports.

Comment: What about mutually recursive functions? How are they interpreted in categorical semantics?

Comment: @ice1000 Well, a set of mutually recursive functions over a set of mutually inductively defined types is just the ordinary recursion principle for that set encoded as an indexed family.  And a set of mutually recursive functions over the *same* type is just an ordinary recursive function into a product type.  For more general kinds of mutual recursion, I'd consider that part of the question!

Comment: I found this: https://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/inductive.html

Comment: @ice1000 I think those are the existing papers on induction-recursion that I mentioned in the question.  Is there one that you think goes further?

Comment: @mikeshulman nope, just sharing a related link :)