# Can you have nonstrict positive inductive types predicatively?

Tags: strict-positivity

So nonstrict positive inductive types are inconsistent with impredicativity (e.g. [here](https://vilhelms.github.io/posts/why-must-inductive-types-be-strictly-positive/), or Coquand and Paulin-Mohring's *Inductively Defined Types*), but can you have them in a predicative setting, such as in Agda? For instance, being allowed to define the following inductive:

```hs
data A : Set₁ where
  a : ((A → Set) → Set) → A
```

It seems there's been conjectures that it's consistent (e.g. [here](https://lists.chalmers.se/pipermail/agda/2013/006189.html)), but not something more definitive.

As followups:

1. Is there a reason Agda checks strict positivity and not merely positivity? As something with quite a lot of [exotic features](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/2002/13) I would have expected it here; I do see that they have an [open issue](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/5284) for it.
2. Would having nonstrict positive inductives be *useful*? I see strict positivity being turned off from time to time to allow negative inductives for HOAS etc., but I don't think I've seen an application of nonstrict positivity.

Answer (score 6):

An answer from [elsewhere](https://types.pl/@koronkebitch/111942623735072179): The counterexamples in type systems site has a page on [Positivity, strict and otherwise](https://counterexamples.org/strict-positivity.html) which cites Blanqui's [Inductive types in the Calculus of Algebraic Constructions](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0610070), which shows in Section 7 that nonstrictly positive inductives can correspond to an admissible recursor in CAC, and Abel's [A semantical analysis of structural recursion](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eabel/dipl-abs/), which in Section 7.1 extends to simply-typed language with nonstrict recursive types.

EDIT: On closer inspection, CAC only has two universes, and only walks through one particular example of a nonstrict positive inductive, so it's unclear whether all nonstrict positive inductives with large elimination is allowed (i.e. in Coq's `Set`).

Answer (score 1):

First I want to note that this statement: "So nonstrict positive inductive types are inconsistent with impredicativity" is not something I believe to be true.

There are some examples of non-strictly positive inductive types in the literature, for instance "Martin Hofmann’s Case for Non-Strictly Positive
Data Types" describes a breadth-first search traversal that goes through an intermediary `Rou` type that is not strictly positive.

The construction in that paper is trivially formalized in Cedille (see a code listing here: https://gist.github.com/amarmaduke/9d8f60addf8eb5a8ba371b2de3eb54e7). Note that Cedille is an impredicative theory with a realizability model (shown in "Syntax and Semantics of Cedille"). As a brief aside, why does your stated counterexample not work? Because it would require the construction of an inductive-kind in Cedille, there is no way to make `Phi : (A -> *) -> *` and use it in inductive types. You could *probably* construct an internal universe via simulated large eliminations, but this would at most show your internal universe is inconsistent, not the builtin universe of types or kinds.

A bit more speculatively, I think that hyperfunctions are an under-explored area of non-strictly positive functions, but you need to take this with a grain of salt because it's really outside my area of expertise. See https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2021-03-14-hyperfunctions.html for a decent introduction with some references.

Comment: Ah, so it's really nonstrict positive inductives + impredicativity + large elimination maybe?

Comment: The counterexamples site you mentioned in your answer gives what I believe to be an adequate description of the three requirements: Prop needs to be treatable as a type (not possible in Cedille), positive inductives (at a higher universe that contains Prop) and impredicativity (just at Prop, not the higher universe containing Prop).